# seemed irritated/annoyed with them

Tags: word-choice, idiomatic-language

They thought you seemed irritated/annoyed with them.

As I understand it, irritated and annoyed are pretty much interchangeable. I thought annoyed was a bit stronger in meaning, but that's not so? Also, are they equally natural in speech if you were to use the sentence I wrote? Thank you.

Comment: In my opinion, *Irritated* sounds more formal while *annoyed* not so much, and I agree that I feel like annoyed has a stronger meaning.

Comment: Using the slash in the sentence you wrote has limited acceptability in writing, since it is appropriate in limited situations.  Are you asking specifically about the acceptability of that sentence with the slash, or are you saking about the differences between the two words?

Comment: ...The difference between the two words.

Comment: I know it requires more work, but you will get a better response if you look the words up in a dictionary and then ask about what still confuses you.  You can even quote and contrast parts of the definition here.  Otherwise, we are going to have to guess at the context you are imaging and may not give the best answer.

Comment: Oxford Languages regards _annoy_ and _irritate_ as synonyms. See [this question](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/216567/annoy-irritate-or-bother?rq=1)

Comment: My question was more about which of them would be most natural in speech, which I can't look up in a dictionary.

Comment: In my opinion, "irritated" is stronger than "annoyed."  They are nearly equivalent in meaning--in the dictionary, each word is used to define the other--but to say "irritated" requires more syllables, and can be perceived as more emphatic by consequence.  Whenever more syllables are required to say one word over another of equivalent meaning, it may share this perception of emphasis.  For example, "I was absolutely dumbfounded" sounds more emphatic than "I was quite amazed."

Comment: **annoy** and **irritate** are in the same register. And they are basically interchangeable. Please use a dictionary before posting. Thanks.